# Transferir arquivo para servidor linux com Python

Tags: python, linux, centos

Olá,

Estou querendo fazer um arquivo **Python** que transfira todos os arquivos de uma pasta local do meu **Windows** para um caminho específico no meu servidor **CentOS 7**. A princípio esse servidor está na minha **rede local**, mas seria interessante futuramente fazer uma transferência para um **servidor externo**.

Qualquer dica de como eu posso fazer esse procedimento com o python já será de grande ajuda!

*Qualquer duvida, estou a disposição.*

Comment: O CentOS tem servidor SSH ou FTP? O Windows tem "samba"?

Comment: Opa, sim tenho acesso pelo SSH, normalmente uso o Putty.  Vou fazer o teste do pysftp e dou um retorno, valeu!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se o CentOS tiver acesso via SSH/SFTP pode instalar o modulo https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pysftp e executar um script python assim:

```
import pysftp

with pysftp.Connection('NOME DO HOST', username='USUARIO', password='SENHA') as sftp:
    with sftp.cd('public'):             # navega para uma pasta especifica
        sftp.put('c:/foo/bar/baz.txt')  # faz o upload para a pasta public
```

> **nota:** a instalação parece não estar disponível via `pip`, você pode baixar o `.tar.gz`